# Reflexxes library for the PR2

Tags: ros, joint-trajectory-action

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to work on integrating the academic version of the reflexxes library ([www.relfexxes.com](http://www.relfexxes.com)). Has anyone started working in this direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61606/reflexxes-library-for-the-pr2/) by [jmainpri](https://answers.ros.org/users/4656/jmainpri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like MoveIt! may use Reflexxes Type II somewhere: http://moveit.ros.org/doxygen/add__time__parameterization_8cpp_source.html , and I know MoveIt! can be used on the PR2.

Beyond that, I'm not aware of any work integrating Reflexxes with the PR2.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1